# How to configure Ransack Rails Gem to add NULLS LAST to sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I would like Ransack to always add `NULLS LAST` which will put nulls last for the sort column.

Any way to do this?

I opened a github issue on this one: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/443

Answer (score 2):

The answer is found in the thread linked in the question above. Writing it here so its easier to find. Apparently you need to build the order string again and add `Null Last` to it.

This solved it for me (works on all columns):

```
@q.result.except(:order).order("#{@q.sorts.first.name} #{@q.sorts.first.dir} NULLS LAST")
```

However you need to exclude it when you don't have any sort parametre, so this is my final solution:

```
@q = Project.ransack(params[:q])
@fields = current_user.settings.default_project_fields
if @q.sorts.present?
  @result = @q.result.except(:order).order("#{@q.sorts.first.name} #{@q.sorts.first.dir} NULLS LAST")
else
  @result = @q.result
end
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but does not work when sorting on associated records, as it uses the raw value from the sort link... for example an `ORDER BY tasks.created_at` will be `ORDER BY tasks_created_at` after the order rewrite

Comment: @agbodike Any solution to sorting on associated records?

Comment: No, but I deferred the task as it's not urgent, so I didn't spend too much time looking for an alternative.